# JavaFX CSS Styling from Java

Tags: css, javafx, stylesheet

I want to assign a style class to an element.

I have a css:

```
.text-field{
    -fx-background-color: #333333;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 -1 -1 -1, 0 0 0 0, 0 -1 3 -1;
    -fx-text-fill: white; 
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
}

.text-field:focused{
    -fx-focus-color: white;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: white;
    -fx-highlight-fill:  grey ;
}
```

And the java code I´m using:

```
JFXTextField textField = new JFXTextField();                    
textField.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("/css/TextField_Style_Sheet.css").toExternalForm());
textField.getStyleClass().clear();
textField.getStyleClass().add("text-field");
```

The problem I´m having is that the ":focused" style is not being applied to this element.
What am I doing wrong?

Already tested it using directly scenebuilder in the element and it seems that the setting in "Focus Color" and "UnFocus Color" options override the text-field:focused style.
As the JFXTextField is created in runtime it seems the default Focus Color overrides the css text-field:focused style.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Aside. Can't see any `-fx-focus-color` in https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#control

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès It's a looked-up color defined in the default style sheet; it's not a CSS property, so it's not in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replace all the style classes of the node with a single style class: `text-field`.

Take a look at modena.css to see that the style of `TextField`s is defined in rules for style class `text-input`.

These rules are also the only place where the ***CSS variable*** `-fx-focus-color` is used for `TextField`s. Since you make sure those rules are no longer applied you don't see any visible effect when modifying the `-fx-focus-color` variable.

If you do want to keep the parts of the old style you should not remove the style classes that are added when creating the node and modify properties that don't suit your needs in your own style. If you clear the style classes you're responsible for rebuilding the look from scratch.

Comment: I still don´t get what I have to do. Already commented the getStyleClass().clear() line but it does nothing.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. Using your stylesheet with a `JFXTextField` does change it's look after all unless you assign the properties from code as well. In this case those values have a higher priority.

Comment: Great! that worked for me. If you place your comment as an answer I check it as a valid answer for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change `focused` to `hover`
like this:
.text-field:hover {
..}